# How do I make two identical images move separate of each other?

Tags: java

so I'm in intro to java and my skills are limited, our teacher wants us to make a screen saver.  My goal here is 2 have multiple hot air balloon objects bounce around the screen at the same time, when they hit a wall they change direction randomly. I got one balloon to bounce randomly except that it wigs out sometimes and still goes off the screen, i assume that issue is in my math though.
The issue I need help with is that when I add a second image to the applet both images seem linked, they move the exact same and when one changes direction so does the other the only thing that differs is starting coordinates, how do I make them move separate of each other?
heres my code.

```
***
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class HotAirBalloons extends GraphicsProgram
{

    private static final int APPLET_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int APPLET_HEIGHT = 600;
    private int speedX = 1;
    private int speedY = 1;

    public void init()
    {
        setSize(APPLET_WIDTH,APPLET_HEIGHT);
        setBackground(new Color(100,210,255));
    }

    public void moveRandomDirection()
    {
        double direction = Math.random() * 2.0 * Math.PI;
        double speed = 3.0;
        speedX = (int) (speed * Math.cos(direction));
        speedY = (int) (speed * Math.sin(direction));
    }

    public void run()
    {

        GImage img1 = new GImage("balloon.jpg");
        add(img1, 0, 0);
        GImage img2 = new GImage("balloon.jpg");
        add(img2, 200, 200);

        while(true)
        {
            pause(15);
            img1.move(speedX, speedY);
            img2.move(speedX, speedY);

            if (img1.getX() > APPLET_WIDTH - 50)
            {
                moveRandomDirection(); 
            }

            if (img1.getX() < 1)
            {
                moveRandomDirection(); 
            }

            if (img1.getY() +85 > APPLET_HEIGHT)
            {
                moveRandomDirection(); 
            }
            if (img1.getY() < 1)
            {
                moveRandomDirection(); 
            }
            if (img2.getX() > APPLET_WIDTH - 50)
            {
                moveRandomDirection(); 
            }

            if (img2.getX() < 1)
            {
                moveRandomDirection(); 
            }

            if (img2.getY() +85 > APPLET_HEIGHT)
            {
                moveRandomDirection(); 
            }
            if (img2.getY() < 1)
            {
                moveRandomDirection(); 
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;

public class HotAirBalloons extends GraphicsProgram
{
    private int speed1 = new Point(1, 1);
    private int speed2 = new Point(1, 1);

    public Point moveRandomDirection()
        {
            double direction = Math.random() * 2.0 * Math.PI;
            double speed = 3.0;
            return new Point((int) (speed * Math.cos(direction)), (int) (speed * Math.sin(direction)));
        }

    public void run()
    {

        GImage img1 = new GImage("balloon.jpg");
        add(img1, 0, 0);
        GImage img2 = new GImage("balloon.jpg");
        add(img2, 200, 200);

        while(true)
        {
            pause(15);
            img1.move(speed1.x, speed1.y);
            img2.move(speed2.x, speed2.y);



            if (img1.getX() > APPLET_WIDTH - 50 || img1.getX() < 1)
            {
                speed1 = moveRandowmDirection();
            }

            if (img1.getY() +85 > APPLET_HEIGHT || img1.getY() < 1)
            {
                speed1 = moveRandomDirection(); 
            }

            if (img2.getX() > APPLET_WIDTH - 50 || img2.getX() < 1)
            {
                speed2 = moveRandomDirection(); 
            }

            if (img2.getY() +85 > APPLET_HEIGHT || img2.getY() < 1)
            {
                speed2 = moveRandomDirection(); 
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Edit: This fixes the 'linked' behavior, and I up voted Rob Watts' response for fixing the issue when the images collide with the edge.

Comment: After plugging it in it almost works perfectly, but it still seems like the balloons are linked in some way, when balloon 2 hits a wall balloon one changes direction as well even though it wasn't near a wall and vice versa, they go in completely opposite random directions properly but its weird to see one switch without a wall hit.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look.  I will edit the answer to reflect changes.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same speedX and speedY variable for both of the balloons. Give them their own speed variables.

Also, the reason why the balloons "wig out sometimes" is that when you choose a random direction, you don't specify that it can't be in the direction that you're trying to get them to go away from.

To fix that issue, I'd suggest that you create a moveRandomDirection method for each balloon, an pass in a value that represents which edge they have hit. Then restrict the direction they can move to be any of the other directions.

Try this:

```
public void moveBalloonOneInRandomDirection(int whichEdge)
{
    double direction = 0;
    switch(whichEdge) {
    case(0): // Top edge
        direction = Math.random() * Math.PI + ONLY_ALLOW_DOWN_VAL;
    case(1): // Left edge
        direction = Math.random() * Math.PI + ONLY_ALLOW_RIGHT_VAL;
    case(2): // Bottom edge
        direction = Math.random() * Math.PI + ONLY_ALLOW_UP_VAL;
    case(3): // Right edge
        direction = Math.random() * Math.PI + ONLY_ALLOW_LEFT_VAL;
    }
    double direction = Math.random() * 2.0 * Math.PI;
    double speed = 3.0;
    speedX1 = (int) (speed * Math.cos(direction));
    speedY1 = (int) (speed * Math.sin(direction));
}
```

Then in your if statements, you would have something like this:

```
if (img1.getX() > APPLET_WIDTH - 50) // Right edge
{
    moveBalloonOneInRandomDirection(3);
}
```

You should probably also use constants, so that instead of the "magic numbers", you would have

```
private static final int RIGHT_EDGE = 3;
...
moveBalloonOneInRandomDirection(RIGHT_EDGE);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for helping with my other issue! I might learn this stuff after all =)